# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused error in laravel when using whereHas

Tags: mysql, laravel, pdo, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Facing a strange issue in laravel. Everything works fine normally database working fine for normal read/write operations and for regular eloquent queries. But when I use

```
$query->whereHas('some_related_model',function($q){
         $q->whereIn('column_on_related_model_table',[array_values]);

})
```

It gives connect refused error as show in the title
I am using `laravel 6.x`, `mySql 8.0` and `php v7.4`

I have written a generalized code above. It happens for every whereHas specially inverse relationships like `BelongsTo`

Comment: put a `return` before the `$q->` inside the closure

Comment: I have tried that too. I didn't work.

Comment: Query builder is an object and by reference so return does not matter.

Comment: @mrhn yes but in anxiety, I gave that a short too haha.

Comment: Issues seems with `mySql 8.0` I have migrated to `mariaDB 10.3` and everything works fine. I am not sure what configurations in mySql were actually causing this error. I will post an answer as soon I find the actual configuration issues

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered the same issue. Turns out it was because of a global scope, which was included on the relationship model. The global scope added a count of children to the relationship. Without the global scope, it worked fine. I haven't really paid more attention to it, as to why it failed with global scope, because the count isn't needed for the initial query.